# How to get data from multiple collection in loop

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

When I try to get data from multiple collections code it is giving me data only from the first collection
i.e collections are project_0, project_1, project_2, project_3

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++){
   $dm->getClassMetadata('\Application\Document\Product')->setCollection('product_'. $i);
   $record = $dm->getRepository('\Application\Document\Product')->findOneBy($condition);
   print_r($record);

}
```

I tried to clear flush but noting is working. Please let me know the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the code above will save the information only from the last collection in `$record` as you are overwriting the data in it with every iteration.

To fix it, you can create an array, let's say `$records = array();` and then in each iteration you can do something like this:

```
array_push($records, $dm->getRepository('\Application\Document\Product')->findOneBy($condition));
```

After you're done, you'll have all the data in `$records`. I hope that helps.

Comment: no this is not the case i already print $record in loop but it is not working

Comment: There is no print statement in the code above so please provide the full version of the code that you are using and eventually further explanations describing your goal?

Comment: Ok, there is a print statement now. I would suggest that the problem comes from the values of '$condition' as the value for it does not change anywhere but you'll need to provide more code....

Comment: condition is same for all collections only collection name is changing

Comment: The line that you have will always return the same value if '$condition' is not changing. The line that you have above it is also a 'get' statement which means that you are not changing anything as far as I understand....

Comment: change collection name ->setCollection('product_'. $i);

Comment: In that case probably one of those two functions that you're calling is at fault but we'll need to see more code to be sure

Comment: this is the only code i want to get data from multiple collection. when i tried this code as single attempt it is working but when i use loop it is returning only first collection data. i thing odm store data in cache. but flush or clear method is not working